# Why does the AI always attack Player 2 (my brother)?

Tags: age-of-mythology

I play a lot of *Age of Mythology* with my brother, and 9 out of 10 games he gets attacked early by the AI, and often these attacks might last the entire game, relentlessly.

I'm always the host, the setup usually looks like this:

- **Player 1: Me** (Team 1)
- **Player 2: My brother** (Team 1)
- **Player 3: AI** (Team 2. Mode: Standard. Difficulty: Hard)
- **Player 4: AI** (Team 2. Mode: Standard. Difficulty: Hard)

I'm usually able to build a stronger economy early on, and I'm often leading the score. I wonder if that might cause the AI to attack him because he's weaker?

Is there some way that I can increase the aggro of the AI on me, so that it attacks me more often as well?

Comment: I don't suppose you have some more information on your and your brother's score progressions early on in the game? If I remember you can see score progression at the end of a match

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I will try to remember to capture a screenshot on our next game and I'll share it here, thanks

Comment: Not a problem, let us know. I have some suspicions but want to confirm based on your scores first!

Comment: Just checking in, any updates on scores?

Comment: Mister @B.S.Morganstein, I have not forgotten you! I and my brother used to play all the time, he flew in to visit us, though, and since we didn't have computers we didn't play much. We are also playing a lot of Age of Empires 2: Definitive Edition, but the hunger for Age of Mythology grows by the day. I shall return with results soon. Thank you for remembering this.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the AI should know to be making their decision is that **Player 2 has not yet advanced to w/e age you guys are** and is therefore a softer target. Always let P2 be an age ahead of you, if you can manage it.

Nothing to back it up but IME the host, Player 1, always gets priority for the best starting spot. Make them host so that you're player 2.

Or just make your own maps with a single entrance with enough space and resources for two.